# VS2013 MVC/WebApi project template returns 401 when using bearer token

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

So this might need to be filed under "you're doing it wrong" but I cannot get the OAuth access_token returned by the default VS2013 MVC5/WebApi project template to successfully authenticate a WebApi request. Interestingly enough, the VS2013 SPA project template seems to work fine.

This should be reproducible by the following steps:

1. In VS2013, do File -> New Project -> Web -> Single Page Application
2. In Startup.Auth.cs uncomment the line:

   ```
   app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
   ```
3. Create a new WebApi controller and a GET action to return some data and add the [Authorize] attribute to the controller.
4. Start Fiddler, F5 debug the application, and browse
   to:

   ```
   http://localhost:<your_port>/api/account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
   ```
5. Open the json file returned from step 4 and copy and paste the entire url value (except the beginning "/") to the end of the address in your address bar and press enter - you should be taken to Google to authenticate.
6. Once you've authenticated you will be redirected back to the SPA app - ignore the "External login failed." error message.
7. Look at the Fiddler trace for the first request to your app after authenticating with Google. Highlight that request and click on the Inspectors tab and then view the Headers of the Response.
8. Copy and paste the Location header under the Transport section into Notepad and then copy only the value of the access_token fragment.
9. In Fiddler, click the Composer tab and modify the default URL to be the URL for the controller action you created in step 3 above.
10. In the Request Headers area add the following below the User-Agent header:

    ```
    Authorization: Bearer [access_token]
    ```

    where [access_token] is the value you copied from step 8 above.
11. Execute the request and you should see HTTP 200 in the Fiddler trace. Viewing the Raw response in the Inspectors tab should show the value(s) you returned from the WebApi method.

If you follow steps 1-11 above with the only change being you choose an MVC/WebApi with Individual User Accounts as the authentication type then you will get an HTTP 401 in step 11 instead of HTTP 200 with the appropriate return data.

Having said all that, am I doing it wrong? As far as I can tell, the two project templates are nearly identical with regards to the OAuth/security setup (some minor differences in web.config but changing those didn't seem to make a difference).

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide - I've been banging my head on the desk for the past couple nights...

Ryan

Comment: Same here - did you ever solve this? I'm getting back a bearer token from facebook, but setting it as Authorization header does not authenticate with WebAPI, returning in a '401' error.

Comment: Honestly, I ended up going with the SPA template which works and scrapped everything I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to enable the WebAPI to use bearer tokens, else I would always get 401. WebAPIs are configured in parallel to the main MVC/Owin app configuration. The line `config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));` in WebApiConfig.cs fixed my issue:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        ...
    }
}
```

This causes WebApi to authenticate via Owin's bearer token authentication.